# Is this the right way to understand Statistical Process Control chart false positives?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I'm a novice here, but what I've read about statistical process control charts says that the "common cause" variation is captured within the 3 sigma upper and lower control limits.

Just checking my understanding, but that's not 100% accurate, correct? Assuming the variation manifests in a normal distribution, there would still be about a 1/400 false positive rate, since 3 sigma on both sides covers 99.73% of the values in the distribution?

If so, why does a single point outside the control limits cause a process to be considered "out of control"? Wouldn't a single point be expected at that 1/400 rate?

Apologies for what feels like a very basic question, but I want to make sure that I've got a solid understanding of the basics.

Comment: Please edit your question to spell out each abbreviation at its first use, or simply use the full form instead of an abbreviation.

Comment: What *action* is taken when an observation falls outside the control limits? It'll be something like sending round a production engineer to check nothing's gone awry, not just proclaiming that the process is out of control.

Comment: So, if I understand, "out of control" means "time to investigate", not that something's wrong? I.e. The term "false positive" doesn't come into play until after the control chart had done it's job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your numbers are right (I make it 1/370).

Each real-life process is different, some are more accurate than others. For one process, 1/400 would be too coarse - for another, it would be too fine. But once you have selected a sensible limit, any value outside that is significant.

Real-life processes can also change over time, eg wear in a machine tool.